# iOS app - write to a mysql database

Tags: ios, mysql, cocoa, swift, connection

Background: I'm familiar with ASP.Net Web Form programming where I code the front end in a .aspx file and the logic in the .aspx.cs code-behind file, however, I recently started to learn about iOS development.

I've managed to create an app where I can read data from a mysql database using this guide here - http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/

However, I was wondering in simple terms, how can I write to a mysql database.

For example, the app UI has a textbox, a label and a submit button, and upon clicking the submit button, I want to write the data inputted to the label and a mysql database.

So I add an action to the button and write the logic in the ViewController.m file e.g.

```
- (IBAction)ouputAge:(UIButton *)sender {

float age = [self.txtInput.text floatValue];
self.lblOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", age];

self.txtInput.resignFirstResponder;
}
```

Now normally, if I was using Web Forms, I would open a connection to the database, define a sql command and execute the query... However, am I correct in saying that I can't do this with iOS development?  What is the most 'efficient' way to do this?  Can anyone point in the direction to useful resources?

Thanks

Comment: What is the intent here? To design app that saves information in so me local database? In that case you usually use Core Data or SQLite. Or do you want to save information in some database on a central server (in which case you'd probably design a web service to receive requests from your device, and only it would interface directly with the MySQL database).

Comment: By the way, while the language isn't critical at this point, you tagged you question with the Swift tag, but provided an Objective-C code sample.

Comment: @Rob On a central server.  To design the web service, I guess I should learn php?

Comment: Yep. Write a JSON interface in PHP that app will interface with, have that web service interface with MySQL database via [MySQL Improved Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).